# How to merge an image into the background along two edges?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, opacitymask

I'm trying to create a stylish effect in my app that allows an image to sit in the top right hand corner with the left and bottom edges merging into the background colour using `Image.OpacityMask`.  Something like:

[image]

This could be done using the following code, except `Image.OpacityMask` only allows for one child `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
    <Image Source="Images/poster.jpg" Width="300">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1, 0.5" EndPoint="0, 0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
```

How can I create an `Image.OpacityMask` like this with valid code?  I'm aware that there is a `RadialGradientBrush`, but this would blend the whole image, not just the left and bottom edges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Brush - I want two gradients chaining them together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834364/custom-brush-i-want-two-gradients-chaining-them-together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two elements, e.g. an Image in a Border:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1, 0.5" EndPoint="0, 0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
    <Image Source="Images/poster.jpg">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
</Border>
```